# Where were we first given the Angels' names?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Neon_Genesis_Evangelion_episodes) and a bunch of other sites, we are given the names of a number of Angels, such as Sachiel and Ramiel. Yet at least in the subbed version of the original 26 episodes that I've been watching - I just got to episode 12 - I haven't seen much (if any) mention of the Angels' names. (Comparatively, I remember seeing the names of new monsters being listed as they appear in-episode in shows such as *Ultraman Max*. It's of course possible that I might have missed something similar in EVA, but I feel like it's hard to get through this many episodes without noticing at some point.)

Where are the names from? From sites such as [this one](http://www.evamonkey.com/platinum-booklets/angel-profiles.php), it seems that there is definitely official information out there, but at least in this case, this is only information for a "platinum DVD release", which would probably be quite a bit later from the original broadcast.

Thus: When and where did viewers *first* learn of the Angels' names? Was this within the original broadcast, or was this perhaps in something like an artbook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the episode 14 "Weaving of a Story" where there is a quick recap of the show up to that point (up to the 11th Angel, although Ireul's name wasn't given in episode 14), and the proper names of the Angels are listed in the eye-catch text, there is also episode 23 where there's a recap of all the angels up to that point, including a picture of the Angel, the number, and name. It occurs right after the halfway point, see: https://wiki.evageeks.org/FGC:Episode_23_Cut_198 for the entire sequence.

This appeared during the original airing of the series on TV, and would be the first time the names are given for all the Angels to the viewer. Note that "Lilith"'s second Angel designation never appears in the TV series, "Kaworu" doesn't appear until episode 24, and the name "Tabris" never appears in the TV series either.

Comment: Except, if I remember correctly, Lilith is crucified in the basement of NERV with the Lance of Longinus stabbed through it. It was originally identified as Adam, but when Kaworu descends to that level, attempting to find Adam, and says something like "Lilith - Lilim, of course!" and that's what changes his mind.

Comment: @ConMan You're right, Kaworu mentioned Lilith as well as Seele in EoE. What I meant to say is that the "Second Angel" designation never appeared in the series/movies.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I think Adam & Lilith's designations originally came from the Red Cross Book, didn't they?

Comment: @ConMan Adam they knew was 1st Angel (From Episode 15, Misato says: "Adam? The First Angel is here?" when Kaji goes down to show her Lilith). The special edition of the Death & Rebirth theatrical booklet (the one that was mail order only and available after all the movies had their theatrical run) mentions the 2nd Angel, not the RCB, but I *think* the very first mention was the [Bandai NGE Card Game](https://wiki.evageeks.org/Neon_Genesis_Evangelion:_The_Card_Game).

Comment: Aha. That does sound familiar. It's been an awfully long time since I watched the show.